# What is causing requests to this url/path?

Tags: html, security, infinity

My company is hosting an ecom shop based on Infinity Shop System. Our logs say that there are HTTP calls to this path which lead to 404 errors since the file does not exist:

> http://{domain}/{somePath}/skin/default/images/tb-collectingalarm-red-low_inject.png

However, this reference is not made by us as I cannot find this path in any line of our source code.

The logs also state that only (some?) Firefox users do this call:

> User Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101
>   Firefox/35.0

So, since this does cause quite some 404 errors, does anyone know what could cause these requests?

We already followed the referrer URL which lead to one of our sites but within its html markup we could not find any reference.

Comment: Add referer to the logs then you might see the source.

Comment: You mean that someone is trying to get this resource & might be using FF, but you can't find any line of code that points to this resource?

Comment: @Seti Please re-read the last sentence of my question

Comment: @IvankaTodorova That's correct